# node.js v10.0.0 messing with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, pm2

I have node.js api project that was working quite fine with node.js `v8.1.4` & npm `v5.0.3` but as I moved to node.js `v10.0.0` & npm `v5.6.0`, it is yielding this:

> core-api@0.0.2 ecosystem E:\opensource\node-cheat\core-api
>   gulp compile && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js | bunyan
>
> gulp[11100]: src\node_contextify.cc:631: Assertion
>   `args[1]->IsString()' failed.  1: node::DecodeWrite  2:
>   node::DecodeWrite  3: uv_loop_fork  4:
>   v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeDecoder::Decode  5:
>   v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec  6: v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec  7:
>   v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec  8: 000000E5F6F84281 npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 134 npm ERR! core-api@0.0.2 ecosystem:`
>   gulp compile && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js | bunyan` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 134 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the core-api@0.0.2
>   ecosystem script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
>   There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\zeeshan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-05-06T11_29_32_241Z-debug.log

how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, it is already faced by many [Github Link](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2162)

Solution 1:

> npm update
>
> npm rebuild

Solution 2:

delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

> npm i

Update: For me later worked smoothly.

Comment: either of them?

Comment: yes, either. The solution is to downgrade node to a 8.x version

Comment: The solution works for me, I didn't want to update for gulp 4 yet, so that was the best way for me. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading your Gulp - Node 10 (Upgrading to Gulp 4)

Remove the existing Gulp version that is globally installed on your machine

> npm rm -g gulp

Then, globally install the new Gulp CLI package as follows

> npm install -g gulp-cli

Proceed on installing Gulp 4 locally to your project folder using following command

> npm install --save-dev gulp@next

In Gulp.js 4, gulp.task('name', ['xq', 'x2']); code should be converted as follows

> gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'imagemin'));
>
> // OR
>
> parallel as follows gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('sass',
> 'imagemin'));

Source: https://davidsekar.com/nodejs/upgrading-your-gulp-for-running-with-node-v10

Comment: Gulp v4.0.2 resolved this error for my environment node v10.16.3, npm v6.9.0. I did have to upgrade the gulpfile.js for compatibility as described above.